# How to make CA-signed SSl certificate that works on any browser (without adding the cert to the store or anything)

Tags: static-ip

Right, so, just a bit of background : I've got a R-Pi 4 (2GB) that's running the latest version. Installed OMV (OpenMediaVault) on it. The NAS bit of this project works well... OMV has an online control panel (running with nginx) that I can access through its IP address on my PC. But this panel is HTTP by default, and as I'm opening ports to make this available for maintenance while I'm away, I wanted to activate HTTPS. I understand I need a certificate for that, but when I made a self-signed one, Chrome kept telling me "the site is not secure".

I've given my server a No-IP subdomain-name (grikirk-panel.ddns.net), and I selected the "Web redirect" option, because I want the simple URL (with no port at the end) to redirect to port 52000, which I port forwarded on my router.

Now for the *fun* bit : I have tried many things, but I have to admit I'm now stumped. My certificate, either signed by TrustCor (they're built into the the No-IP panel) or CAcert.org, has the CN <grikirk-panel.ddns.net>, and I added as alternate URI <grikirk-pabel.ddns.net> and <www.grikirk-panel.ddns.net> (apparently CN isn't enough for Chrome anymore, I'll put the link of that if I find it).

The problem with that is No-IP redirects to an IP address, and so the certificate isn't valid anymore ! Even if I add the IP to the certificate, 6 hours later, it's not valid anymore because my public IP address has changed !

Just thought of this while typing : would it be worth giving "grikirk-panel.ddns.net" as the R-Pi  domain name ? But then, I was planning on creating a new No-IP address such as "grikirk-sftp.ddns.net" for the shares. That would mean 2 domain names on the R-Pi, which is impossible, right ?

Please help me, because I'm a bit desesperate in front of :

[image: 1]

That's actually exactly the error I'm getting...

Thanks, Silloky

Comment: `2 domain names on the R-Pi, which is impossible, right` wrong ... mine has 7 public domains and a couple of "private" ones - for website SSL I use letsencrypt - free, easy to setup, and trusted the whole world over

Comment: The way you have no-ip redirecting will stop you from hosting https - but, I know some internet providers do block port 80 and 443, preventing you from doing so

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry for the late response, i finally got a domain off Freenom, with CloudFlare as DNS, created some CNAME records for subdomains, installed nginx proxy manager which has letsencrypt included, and bam, my subdomains are secure. I realized afterwards that my IP was actually static, except if my router turns off too long, but that only happens occasionnally. Thanks for the "letsencrypt" tip !